# Obtain nameserver information for DNS lookups in Java

Tags: java, dns

If I look up a IP address from a DNS name as follows:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(name);
String address = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```

Can I find out which nameserver gave me the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but there's a [DNSJava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) library which provides DNS functionality in Java. Perhaps you can use this to either get a better understanding of your issues, or to implement a particular solution ? Like I say, not a perfect match for you, but perhaps helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For a given InetAddress, try the following:

```
// get the default initial Directory Context
InitialDirContext idc = new InitialDirContext();
// get the DNS records for inetAddress
Attributes attributes = idc.getAttributes("dns:/" + inetAddress.getHostName());
// get an enumeration of the attributes and print them out
NamingEnumeration attributeEnumeration = attributes.getAll();
System.out.println("-- DNS INFORMATION --");
while (attributeEnumeration.hasMore()) {
    System.out.println("" + attributeEnumeration.next());
}
attributeEnumeration.close();
```

Adapt it to pick up what you're looking for.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I just got the A records, no other attributes. Maybe an environmental thing.

Comment: Well, *An A record gives you the IP address of a domain*. Isn't this precisely what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

you need an Naming Context. Optional you can Specify the DNS Server.
And even then you need to select that you are looking for. Here is an example.

```
final String ADDR_ATTRIB = "A";
final String[] ADDR_ATTRIBS = {ADDR_ATTRIB};
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
idc = new InitialDirContext(env);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "dns://"+dnsServer);
final List<String> ipAddresses = new LinkedList<>();
final Attributes attrs = idc.getAttributes(hostname, ADDR_ATTRIBS);
final Attribute attr = attrs.get(ADDR_ATTRIB);
if (attr != null) for (int i = 0; i < attr.size(); i++)  ipAddresses.add((String) attr.get(i));
```